# Rolling mean for a row from column x on wards

Tags: mean

I have a large data set with multiple rows and columns. I want to calculate the rolling mean for each cell in a row from column x on wards. Similarly I want to calculate the standard deviation as well. How can I do it? Also I want to do so for all the rows

Answer (score 0):

In what programming language, what kind of file.

General math for rolling mean would be

```
average = column x
for element in range (column x+1 to y)
  average = (average + element)/2
```

Standard deviation is a lot more complex and you'd be better off using a library for it.

For python - get scipy or just numpy

javascipt - base math library

Comment: I am doing it in R, where my data for each row starts from column 33. Since my rolling window is 60 I should get my first output at column 93. I am not sure how to write the code and hence could use your help

Comment: It is a csv file